# Native Android multi-threaded odd occurrence

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, opengl-es

I've been working on this game at the native Android /NDK level. To start off with I had only a single texture but as my textures hit 5, my fps slowly reduced to about 20 (with stutters) from around 60.

Currently im performing all my operations on a single thread. On the introduction of another thread using posix threads with a start_routine (which loops infinitely and has no implementation), my fps seemed to have hit about 40 for no apparent reason.

Another point here was that after introduction of that thread, the FPS was stable at 42-43. But without the thread, there were stutters (18-28 fps) causing jerky animation. 
My doubts:

1. Why the above mentioned is happening (thread related)?
2. Also, the only difference between when I was using 1 texture was that the calculations in my fragment shader are more now. Does that mean the GPU is being overloaded and hence glSwapBuffers taking more time?
3. Assuming glSwapBuffers does take time, does that mean my game logic is always going to be ahead of my renderer?
4. How exactly do i go about feeding the render thread with the information needed to render a frame? As in do i make the render thread wait on a queue which is fed by my game logic thread? (Code related)

Code :

```
void * start_render (void * param)
{

    while (1) {

    }

    return NULL;
}

void android_main(struct android_app* state) {


    // Creation of this thread, increased my FPS to around 40 even though start_render wasnt doing     anything

    pthread_t renderthread;
    pthread_create(&renderthread,NULL,start_render,NULL);


    struct engine engine;

    memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(engine));
    state->userData = &engine;
    state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
    state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;


    engine.assetManager = state->activity->assetManager;

    engine.app = state;
    engine.texsize = 4;


    if (state->savedState != NULL) {
        // We are starting with a previous saved state; restore from it.
        engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
    }

    // loop waiting for stuff to do.

    while (1) {
        // Read all pending events.
        int ident;
        int events;
        struct android_poll_source* source;

        // If not animating, we will block forever waiting for events.
        // If animating, we loop until all events are read, then continue
        // to draw the next frame of animation.
        while ((ident=ALooper_pollAll(engine.animating ? 0 : -1, NULL, &events,
                (void**)&source)) >= 0) {

            // Process this event.
            if (source != NULL) {
                source->process(state, source);
            }


            // Check if we are exiting.
            if (state->destroyRequested != 0) {
                engine_term_display(&engine);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (engine.animating) {



                for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
                {
                    float cur = engine.mytextures[i].currentposition;

                    if (cur < 1.0)
                        engine.mytextures[i].currentposition = cur + engine.mytextures[i].relativespeed;
                    else
                        engine.mytextures[i].currentposition = cur - 1.0;
                }

            // How do i enable the render thread (created above) to call the below function?
            on_draw_frame(&engine);




        }
    }
}

void on_draw_frame(engine * engine) {

    glUseProgram(program);

    engine->texsize = 4;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->mytextures[0].textureid);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->mytextures[1].textureid);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->mytextures[2].textureid);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->mytextures[3].textureid);

    glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location1,0);
    glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location2,1);
    glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location3,2);
    glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location4,3);


    glUniform1f(timeCoord1,engine->mytextures[0].currentposition);
    glUniform1f(timeCoord2,engine->mytextures[1].currentposition);
    glUniform1f(timeCoord3,engine->mytextures[2].currentposition);
    glUniform1f(timeCoord4,engine->mytextures[3].currentposition);



    glUniform1i(texSize,engine->texsize);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    glVertexAttribPointer(a_position_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        4 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_texture_coordinates_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        4 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), BUFFER_OFFSET(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_position_location);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_texture_coordinates_location);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);


    // FPS calculation
    if (fps == 0)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &starttime);
    else
        clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&stoptime);

    if (stoptime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec == 1) {

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "GAME", "FPS %d",fps);
        fps = 0;

    } else
        fps++;

}
```

Let me know if you need more information regarding the code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What device are you measuring this on?

Comment: I'm using a nexus 4..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be completely certain, but this looks a lot like bad effects of power management on the device.

The symptoms you describe can be caused by a power management strategy that focuses on CPU usage. With a strategy like this, it can happen that if you have very low CPU usage (because you're mostly GPU limited), the whole system goes to a lower power state, and effectively slows down the GPU, even though the GPU is fully loaded.

In this situation, when you add additional CPU load by starting another thread that burns CPU time, you keep the system in a higher power state, and allow the GPU to run faster.

This kind of power management is completely broken, IMHO. Slowing down the GPU if it's fully busy just because CPU utilization is low does not make any sense to me. But power management on some devices is very primitive, so this kind of behavior is not uncommon.

If this is indeed your problem, there's not much you can do about it as an application developer, beyond filing bugs. Creating artificial CPU load to work around it is of course not satisfying. Using more power to defeat power management is not exactly what you want. Many games will probably generate a significant amount of CPU load to handle their game logic/physics, so they would not be affected.